# Where does the InfoStore service run from?

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm new to development for the Business Objects 4.0 SDK.  I've figured out how to connect to the server.  Through various examples on the web, I've also learned I need to use the InfoStore service to fill in the InfoStore object and get to the meat of the process.  However, I'm still a bit confused.  If I do something like this:

```
SessionMgr sess = new SessionMgr();
EnterpriseSession enterSess = sess.Logon("username", "password", "server", "secEnterprise");
foreach (string server in enterSess.ServerNames.Cast<string>())
    List<string> services = enterSess.GetServiceNames(server, CeServiceType.ceServiceAllServices).Cast<string>().ToList();
```

I never see the InfoStore service come up.  I just happened to trip over...

```
EnterpriseService enterStore = enterSess.GetService("InfoStore");
InfoStore store = new InfoStore(enterStore);
```

...as the solution.

The API does have this line under the EnterpriseSession.GetService() function:

```
BusinessObjects Enterprise developers will only be concerned with the InfoStore service since this is the only service that is supported in BusinessObjects Enterprise.
```

So here's the question:  What is running the InfoStore service?  Is there something I'm missing when searching for services on the BO Server?

Edit: Running through all the servers and calling GetService against them using InfoStore shows that SERVER_NAME.CentralManagementServer is running the service.  There are other servers that run it too, but they return different objects.

New question: Why doesn't CentralManagementServer report it's running InfoStore when it clearly is?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates that it is the [Central Management Server](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsxi/en/en/Viewers_SDK/viewerssdk_java_dg_doc/doc/viewerssdk_java_dg/Tutorials8.html).

Comment: Well yes, you have to log in to CMS to do anything.  Once you get in you can the individual servers via the ServerNames property.  The obvious option SERVER_NAME.CentralManagementServer doesn't show the InfoStore process running when you call GetServices against it.  Putting it into GetService does return the same InfoStore object though.  I went through all the other servers this morning and there are a few others running InfoStore and they return different objects.  I suppose a better question might be why doesn't CMS report the service?